# Loading Custom View from XIB, How to Make it Respond to Custom Subclass?

Tags: ios, objective-c, subclass, xib

I have created a view with a XIB (`MyXIB`) and created a UIView Subclass (`MyViewSubclass`). I set the `MyViewSubclass` as the "Custom Class" for the `MyXIB`'s View.

I have connected a button in `MyXIB` to an IBAction in `MyViewSubclass`.

In the main View Controller of the app, I call:

```
NSArray *subviewArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyXIB" owner:self options:nil];
MyUIViewSubclass *myView = [subviewArray objectAtIndex:0];
[self.view addSubview:myView];
```

This works to add the new view on top of the existing View Controller, but whenever I tap the button from `MyXIB`, the app crashes and says that it is `sending an unrecognized selector` to the Parent View Controller.

How can I get the button on `MyXIB` to invoke the IBAction in `MyViewSubclass` ?

Comment: you have to connect the button action to your view controller class. Not to your custom  view class.

Comment: make sure your custom view file owner is your view controller.

Comment: So if I want to display `MyXIB` across many different screens in my app, do I need to implement the button's method in every UIViewController that accesses MyXIB?

Comment: For what you described, I suggest you create a [protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html) in `MyXIB` and then implement your protocol methods at any controller necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to use the view in other view controllers, you should create a `delegate protocol`, as following:

`MyXIB.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol MyXIBDelegate <NSObject>

@required // if it's not necessary, you can use @optional
- (void)myXIBDelegateMethod;

@end

@interface MyXIB : UIView

@property (weak, nonatomic) id<MyXIBDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

`MyXIB.m`

```
#import "MyXIB.h"

@implementation MyXIB

- (IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender {
    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(myXIBDelegateMethod)]) {
        [self.delegate myXIBDelegateMethod];
    }
}

@end
```

As your UIButton's action is linked in `MyXIB` view, when the button is pressed, you check if the `delegate` property is set and if it responds to you delegate method and then you call your protocol's method.

In your view controller `.m` file at the `@implementation` section, you would have something like the following:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "MyXIB.h"

@interface ViewController () <MyXIBDelegate>

@end
```

And as the protocol method is `@required`, you have to implement the method in the view controller:

```
#pragma mark - MyXIB Delegate Method

- (void)myXIBDelegateMethod {
    // your implementation
}
```